# Docker: open /certs/domain.crt: permission denied

Tags: permissions, docker

I'm trying to setup a private docker registry.
I'm using my own generated certificates. But my docker logs of my registry show this error:

```
time="2015-12-08T08:51:54Z" level=fatal msg="open /certs/domain.crt: permission denied"
```

I have my certificate in:

```
/home/centos/certs/certs/
```

This contains `domain.crt` and `domain.key`

I have a permission denied. But I don't know what's the best solution in this case? Which rights to which user do I have to give?

I just tried to give all the rights but it isn't working:
I tried:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/centos/certs
sudo chown -R root:root /home/centos/certs
```

Answer (score 9):

It's may an issue with SELinux and Docker:

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t ~/certs/
```

Then, try again.

Answer (score 1):

### Disable SElinux in docker registry host

I hit the same (permission denied) issue while i was setting up a private docker registry. Ths issue was SELinux was in Enforcing state. Disabling SELinux solved the issue. You can disable or make it permissive mode by using below command setenforce 0 ---> No reboot required or open the selinux config file vi /etc/selinux/config and change SELINUX=disabled

Comment: Please add enough detail on disabling the same.

Comment: I hit the same (permission denied) issue while i was setting up a private docker registry. Ths issue was SELinux was in Enforcing state. Disabling SELinux solved the issue.
You can disable or make it permissive mode by using below command
setenforce 0    ---> No reboot required
or open the selinux config file 
vi /etc/selinux/config and change SELINUX=disabled

Comment: Please add that to the answer.